# Seeking central user management software

Tags: apache-2.2, active-directory, postfix, ftp, svn

I work in a startup company and recently the number of pieces of software we use started to increase. Because all of them introduce their own user databases I started looking for a solution that could be integrated with them and save me the time of updating every single db when someone compromises a password/joins/leaves.

So far I see that the only solution that is used more widely is ldap. I had bad experience with it in the past, so I was wondering if anyone could recommend an alternative.

For now it would be sufficient if it could be integrated with svn, apache and had php bindings. It would be even more awesome if it could integrate with git, ftp, postfix.

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/ - http://serverfault.com/faq

Answer (score 1):

389 Directory Server / RedHat Directory server - as LDAP database backend. Standard Netscape LDAP. Fast, secure, flexible.

FreeIPA / RedHat IPA - for Identity, Policy and Audit (requires/installs 389/RH DS too). Will use kerberos and identify services via pam names. Centralized, smart, easy, secure.

p.s. Use RHEL 6 or Fedora 17 as server

Comment: We will be using RHEL in the future but for now the solution must work in Ubuntu. And somehow I don't think that using fedora in a server is a good idea.

Comment: It will work. You only need freeipa clients.
Fedora is bad idea and Ubuntu is good? hm... :)
Use it as LDAP/IPA server, client side (including service servers) can be anything, including windows. Otherwise have fun with openldap, SSL with openldap and etc. It's a headache.
RH is de-facto standard solution provider today and fedora community is much stronger than any. The only thing is release cycle which doesn't look like a problem for me - upgrades are easy.

Comment: https://launchpad.net/freeipa